# How to restore postgres dump with RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds, postgresql-9.4

I have a postgres dump in AWS S3 bucket, what is the most convenience way to restore it in a AWS RDS ?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no native AWS way to manually push data from S3 to anywhere else.  The dump stored on S3 needs to first be downloaded and then restored.

You can use the link posted above (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html), however that doesn't help you download the data.

The easiest way to get something off of S3 is to simply go to the S3 console and point/click your way to the file, right click it and click Download.  If you need to restore FROM an EC2 instance (e.g. because your RDS does not have a public IP), than install and configure the AWS CLI (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html).

Once you have the CLI configured, download with the following command:

```
aws s3 cp s3://<<bucket>>/<<folder>>/<<folder>>/<<key>> dump.gz
```

NOTE: the above command may need some additional tweaking depending on whether you have multiple AWS profiles installed on the machine, the dump is not one file (but many), etc.

From there restore to RDS just like you would a normal Postgres server following the instructions in the AWS link.

Hope that helps!